# Mouse DPI level resets to lowest when switched off (Logitech G602, Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, mouse

Since the last two months or so, my mouse started switching on at the lowest setting so I have to amp it back up each time I switch it on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Normally if I switched off my mouse (to conserve battery), it would switch on with the previous DPI level setting. I could not find any relevant settings.

I did not have Logitech Gaming Software installed previously. I installed it recently but it did not change anything and I also do not see any related settings on there.

Edit: The mouse displays the same behaviour if its USB is unplugged.

Comment: Are you sleeping/hibernating/shutting down/restarting the computer? These don't always reset hardware correctly, but disconnecting and reconnecting a USB device usually preserves previous settings, provided you use the same USB port. There is a [new release](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/g602-wireless-gaming-mouse/downloads#windowsPnlBar) of the Logitech Gaming Software.

Comment: I tried changing USB ports, it didn't change anything. But while the USB is unplugged, the mouse displays the same behaviour (I can change the DPI using the buttons on it). So maybe it's from the mouse firmware.

Comment: There is a firmware update on the same page as the gaming software update.

Comment: Also performed the firmware update, no change, still gets lowest DPI setting when switching off and on.

Comment: I can't think of anything else to try: you'll need to contact Logitech support.